# Convert json to text[] in alter table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN hobbies type text[] using hobbies::text[];
```

It is showing an error that json cannot be cast into `text[]`.

Comment: What does your column currently contain? A "JSON array"? e.g. `["foo", "bar"]`?

Comment: Please post a data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a helper function to do that.

```
create function json_to_array(json) returns text[] language sql as $$ 
    select array_agg(x) from json_array_elements_text($1) f(x) 
$$;

ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN hobbies type text[] using json_to_array(hobbies);
```